# How to change button's onclientclick property server side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a button as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Next"
    onclick="btnNext_Click" style="text-align: center" Width="80px" />
```

and a RadNumericTextBox:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtTotal5" runat="server" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="true" 
    MinValue="0" ontextchanged="txtTotal5_TextChanged"><NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" /></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

I need to set the `onClientClick` property based on whether a telerik `RadNumericTextBox` has text in it or not. If it does not have a value, the `onClientClick` property needs to be set as shown below. If there is a value in the box, I want to just go on to the `onclick` event which directs it to the next form.

```
protected void txtTotal5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtTotal5.Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            btnNext.OnClientClick = "javascript: return confirm('Please have the employee complete this form.')";
        }
        else
        {
            btnNext.OnClientClick = "";
        }
    }
```

Now I have used the debugger several times to step through the code, and the value changes as I expect within the function, but even when it sets the `OnClientClick` property to `""`, the box still pops up when the button is clicked. Is the value not being passed to the client somehow? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtTotal5">` inside a repeater or a any ohter loop? Can you add a screenshot or a drawing how the page elements are displayed on the page and how they work togehter?

Comment: It is pretty simple. The text box is only inside a table and the table is inside an updatepanel. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `OnClientClick` to the `Attributes` collection of the button, like this:

```
btnNext.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "YourJavaScriptFunction();");
```

Comment: This is instead of just doing `btnNext.onClientClick = "something"`?

Comment: I tried using that instead but then I never get the box even if the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my issue. I left the function above as is, but I basically copied the if-else into my page_load event inside `if(IsPostBack)`.